# perspective pattern on object in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, patterns, perspective, distort

Currently I am working om a project were I need to make a pattern in perspective on an object. For this I used Envelope distort -> make with top object. For each side I made a seperate envelope distortion. But I want to make a better transition between leftside en rightside. So that you can't see the difference. Now the right side the pattern seem somewhat streched. I just want just the whole pattern in the right perspective on the whole object. Anyone some good suggetions? thnx!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself. envelope distort + clipping mask.

Comment: Do you mind going into further detail?  If you did, I would upvote your answer.  If you also answered your own question please mark it as the solution.